# Selecting range of Range object

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a sheet with holidays of 5 countries in 5 columns (each row is a date of holiday for given country) and I want to use it for `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay` function

```
Sub Func()
   Dim holidays As Worksheet
   Set holidays = Sheets("Holidays")
   Dim lastHolidayRow As Long
   
   lastHolidayRow = holidays.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   holi = holidays.Range("A2:E" & lastHolidayRow).Value

   previous_working_day = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("19.02.2022", -1, holi(3, :)) 

End Sub
```

but I have no idea how to choose entire 3rd column (in many programing languages it would be `holi(3, :)`) for `WorkDay` function.

Also is my `lastHolidayRow` the best way to select all data from that sheet? Some countries has less holidays than others, so am I selecting the last last row correctly?

[image]

for example if my date is `01.01.2010` then `WorkDay` func should return `02.01.2010` (it's DD-MM-YYYY)

Comment: Not tested but maybe `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("19.02.2022", -1, Range("C:C"))` Anyways that's a lot of cells. Are you sure you need to exclude more than 1 million dates? That does not make sense to me. Could you post a data example and expected output?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns added screen of Holidays sheet. I don't understand what u mean as "exclude more than 1kk dates" - am I using `WorkDay` wrongly? I'm new to VBA :/

Comment: [WORKDAY function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) got 3 arguments and the last one (optional) isa range of cells with dates to exclude. If you want to exclude the whole third column, then you want to exclude more than 1 million dates...

Comment: *if my date is 01.01.2010 then WorkDay func should return 02.01.2010* 02.01.2010 was Saturday so it's not a workday so there is no way you can get that result. WORKDAY function **excludes weekends and any dates identified as holidays**

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns sorry, my bad with that example. Lets say we look at PLN column and my date is 06.04.2010 which is Tuesday and I want to get previous working day which is 02.04.2010 (because 03, 04 are weekend and 05 is holiday). To include holiday in 05.04.2010 in no-work days and my Holidays Sheet containt 5 columns and each column has different number of rows

Also `next_working_day` should be `previous_working_day` which I just editted

Comment: So you want to get the previous working day for each country, and each column represents the holidays for each country, right? You can do this easily in Excel, no need of VBA. As Example for PLN with date `06.04.2010`, if the holidays go from A2 to A29, you could do `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("06.04.2010", -1, Range("A2:A29"))`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes, I want to get previous day for given date for each country using their holiday database. I don't want to do this in Excel, bcs it's just the part of my code (I'm also getting other data). 

Finally the code of @tnavidi worked almost perfectly except - if in `WorkDay` function I insert `holi.Range("C:C")` I get `Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`, but with only `holy` it works (but gets holidays of all country, not selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Func()
Dim holidays As Worksheet
Set holidays = Sheets("Holidays")
Dim holi As Range
Dim previous_working_day As Date

Set holi = holidays.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
lastHolidayRow = holidays.Rows.Count

previous_working_day = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("19.02.2022", -1, holidays.Range("A2:A" & lastHolidayRow))

Set holi = Nothing

End Sub
```

Notice the part that says `holidays.Range("A2:A" & lastHolidayRow)`. This is referenced to `PLN` only. If you want to switch to other country change both `A` to whatever column you want. For EUR it would be `holidays.Range("C2:C" & lastHolidayRow)` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be best solution. Also I have got 1 question - is it necessery to declare `previous_working_day`? I mean the code will work even without `Dim` statement right? But without declaring I need to care about datatype that is typed after using the macro

Comment: @Saguro You don't need to declare variables but it's a good practice to avoid errors. I strongly encourage you to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try `Range("C:C")` if I understood your question correctly

```
Sub Func()
   Dim holidays As Worksheet
   Dim holi as Range
   Set holidays = Sheets("Holidays")
   Dim lastHolidayRow As Long
   
   lastHolidayRow = holidays.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   Set holi = holidays.Range("A2:E" & lastHolidayRow)

   next_working_day = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("19.02.2022", -1, holi.Range("C:C")) 

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean holi(Range("C:C"))? I'm getting `Subscript out of range` not sure why

Comment: wait, i've read that wrong, i thought holi was range object, sorry, will edit my response again

Comment: I had to modify it to `Application.WorkDay("19.02.2022", -1, holi.Columns(4)`